# Update (incorrect) timestaps of copied files with original date from the source file

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer, date-time

I copied a rather large folder using Ubuntu (in the magnitude of a few million files, and a couple of terabytes, so synchronizing takes about today). I forgot to set a switch so the copying process replaced the original timestamp of each file with the current time and date.

I looked around but so far I couldn't find any easy-to-implement solutions of course I could use some kind of file comparison tool that would copy the whole file so that doesn't really solve my problem.

I suppose I have to write a script from scratch reading each source file's time and date and replacing it on the destination file, but I hope there is an easier out-of-the-box solution (e.g. some switch for a copy command I'm not aware of or even a third-party tool that supports this feature), or maybe somebody already wrote a script for a similar purpose.

I don't use Linux very frequently, so feel free to include any hints on how to approach this via script (if this turns out the way to go), that would be very much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We should probably be able to cobble something together using the `find` command (to generate a list of files) and the `touch` command (which has the `-r` option to set the mtime of a target file to the value of a reference file).

Maybe something like:

```
(cd /source && find . -type f -print0) |
    (cd /destination && xargs -0 -iPATH sh -c "touch -r '/source/PATH' 'PATH'")
```

The idea here is that:

1. We  generate a list of paths relative to the source directory.
2. We change to the destination directory, and for each of those paths we construct a shell script that applies the `touch -r` command to each path.

We use the `-0` option to both `find` and `xargs` in order to properly handle filenames that contain whitespace.